# Translating a PathGeometry in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there an easy way of translating the PathGeometry in WPF (C#)?

Having a PathGeometry (System.Windows.Media) and a Vector (System.Windows.Vector) i would like to translate the whole Geometry without needing to analyze each single Figure with their Segments and the corresponding Points. The code is pretty straight forward but i'm looking for an approach that uses standard functionality already provided by WPF (C#). Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. By "translate", do you mean geometrically? Applying transformations (like a translation transform) is the "bread and butter" of WPF. `UIElement` objects (some of which are used to present `PathGeometry` data) have `RenderTransform` and `LayoutTransform`. Other objects that use `PathGeometry`, like `DrawingBrush` similarly have transform properties (e.g. `Brush.RelativeTransform` and `Brush.Transform`) as well as properties like `Viewbox` and `Viewport` that further describe how the object is rendered. There's really no shortage of ways to apply transformations.

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain precisely what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: The question was pretty simple, because of that i didn't thought that an code example was required. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7):

Set the Geometry's `Transform` property to an appropriate `TranslateTransform`, e.g.

```
Geometry geometry = ...
Vector translation = ...

geometry.Transform = new TranslateTransform(translation.X, translation.Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking around a bit more I found the solution to my own question:

```
public PathGeometry TranslatePathGeometry(PathGeometry originalGeometry, Vector translationVector)
{
   originalGeometry.Transform = new TranslateTransform(translationVector.X, translationVector.Y);
   return PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(originalGeometry);
}
```

I found other options using the Geometry.Combine method, but this solution i think is more elegant.

As explained by Clemens it's not even necessary to create a new GeometryPath, you can just apply the TranslateTransform and it will work perfectly.

Comment: Your actual question is already answered by "set the Geometry's Transform property". If you had asked how to create a congruent copy of it where the Transform property isn't set, this would be the answer.

Comment: I searched almost 1 hour without finding any solution and then after writing the question I continued trying things out until I manged to find the solution. So i decided  to write about it without noticing that you answered it already. Sorry about that and thanks for your help!